# Stream video from camera to iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, asterisk

I'm working on an app that connects to a security camera. The camera has its own SIP server (Asterisk).

I'm having a very hard time finding a reliable iOS library to connect to the camera.

Can anyone recommend a high-quality SIP library that will stream video? I've tried several so far and none of them are fit for the task (I don't want mention them by name).

Or is there another way to access the video (using webRTC or possibly AVFoundation via the Asterisk server)?

I do not have a lot of experience with hardware, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Asking for a library is not a valid question here.

Answer (score -3):

What are you looking for called MCU(media control unit). There are some free availible for vido, but all are early beta and very hard to setup.